# tkinter/datetime/weekday/dictionary/ type error : strptime() argument 1 must be str, not entry

Tags: dictionary, datetime, tkinter, global, weekday

1. In function (def wky(event)), without 'global ab', it happens next error
   message : 'UnboundLocalError'.  And then, I used that words(global ab).
   But, I wonder that that words is necessary? Without declare the global
   in function, we can't use the local variable?
2. In function, is there wrong sentence? I used the Dictionary. I thought that
   the appropriate value is coming in Dictionary. But, when I run the below code,
   it happened the Error message. What I miss something?
3. In conclusion, this code is that label's value come from in ab variable.
   ab variable's initial value is None. User immediately input any value,
   and then label's value is automatically inserted following press 'Enter'key.

I hope for your merciful help ~ ^^

Below the paragrape, I wrote the code.

---

```py
from tkinter import *

from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()

root.title("Moving")

root.geometry("640x480")

root.resizable(False, False)

def wky(event):

    global ab

    ab = datetime.strptime(ab, "%Y-%m-%d")

    dateDict = {0:"Mon", 1:"Tue", 2:"Wed", 3:"Thu", 4:"Fri", 5:"Sat", 6:"Sun"}

    dateDict[ab.weekday()]

    label.config(text = dateDict[ab.weekday()])

ab = Entry(root)

ab.bind("<Return>", wky)

ab.pack()

label=Label(root)

label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\JS\Desktop\PYTHONWORKSPACE\movingproject\1_name.py", line 145, in wky
    ab = datetime.strptime(ab, "%Y-%m-%d")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Entry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, `ab` is an `Entry` widget that cannot be used in `strptime()`. You need to use the value in the `Entry` widget instead.

Also better use another local variable to store the result of `strptime()` instead of using `ab`:

```py
def wky(event):
    date = datetime.strptime(ab.get(), "%Y-%m-%d")
    dateDict = {0:"Mon", 1:"Tue", 2:"Wed", 3:"Thu", 4:"Fri", 5:"Sat", 6:"Sun"}
    #dateDict[date.weekday()] # this line is useless
    label.config(text=dateDict[date.weekday()])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I solve the problem.  l learn the code from your teaching.   Have  a great day. ~